# Наследование стилей

Tags: wpf, style

Есть базовый стиль, который применяется ко всем кнопкам. Наследую от него другой стиль, который будет использоваться только в одной кнопке. Но тогда этот стиль перебивает базовый и применяется ко всем кнопкам.

Можно ли как-то указать в производном стиле свойство `TargetType`, чтобы оно не указывало ни на один из типов или придётся убирать это свойство из базового стиля, и явно прописывать его у каждой кнопки?

Базовый стиль:

```
<Style x:Key="GeneralButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="150" />
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="300" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle Name="GelBackground" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Fill="#FFB2B2B2"/>
                        <Rectangle Name="GelShine" Margin="1,1,1,1" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,2">
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="#ccffffff" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.6" Color="Transparent" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <ContentPresenter Name="GelButtonContent" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Rectangle.Fill" TargetName="GelBackground">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FF4885CD" />
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FF1B5FF0" />
                                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Rectangle.Fill" TargetName="GelBackground">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FFFFD39F" />
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FFFF9C00" />
                                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Производный:

```
<Style x:Key="SearchButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource GeneralButtonStyle}" >
        <Setter Property="Control.Tag" Value="1"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Control.Tag" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Button.Content" Value="Остановить поиск"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Control.Tag" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Button.Content" Value="Найти приложения"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Можно добавить новому стилю `x:Key`, тогда он не будет применяться ко всем по умолчанию. А кому надо, укажете как раз со ссылкой на ключ.

Comment: У меня так и было. Сейчас кину код

Comment: Я кажется понял, это не производный стиль перебил, это когда я добавил Key к базовому, он перестал действовать неявно. Тогда как сделать, чтобы он действовал неявно с Key? Или может можно пронаследоваться от стиля без Key?)

Comment: Можно сделать наследника без Key. Если наследник совсем без изменений - то фактически будет работать как базовый стиль.

Comment: А как мне тогда его применять без ключа? И что значит совсем без изменений? У меня пара тригеров добавилось в производном.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень просто.

Вот такой код:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#bcd0e5"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#244e81"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="Green" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#d3bb9c"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Button>Стиль по умолчанию</Button>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource Green}">Перекрытый стиль</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

даёт результат:

[image: есть два баттона, на каком дефолтный стиль применишь, на каком перекроешь?]